# Coverity & Jenkins: Howto analyse newly committed code ONLY

Tags: jenkins, static-analysis

I have recently added a new Jenkins job to my automation suite to run coverity analysis on a C++ application. The job uses svn to updade to latest code then uses coverity (cov-build, cov-analyze, and cov-format-errors) and creates a text file of coverity errors. However, the application has been around for a long time and has a lot of coverity errors highlighted. I am looking for a way to run coverity so that it only analyses newly added content?

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: IMHO, only analyzing changed code is not a good idea.  Changes in new code could cause changes to issues in old code.  (Coverity does do some trace through of the code.)   The better solution is to deal with the old issues by either marking them as not an issue (postponed, ignored, etc.); or by solving them.

Comment: Are you committing your defects to the Coverity Connect (or Integrity Manager database)? If so, you could use a filter that ignores all issues found after a given date.

Comment: No I have not done so, I am new to coverity and did not know about this. Is there anywhere I can find examples or a step by step that will help me set up Coverity Connect (or Integrity Manager database)...and then perhaps add to my Jenkins server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do this.  Coverity has no idea what is new code and what is not.

But there is a workaround.  First, make run Coverity on your code, then mark ALL Coverity issues as Ignore and Intentional in the CIM server.  Then, setup your Coverity Plugin to report only when NEW issues are found.

Now, when Coverity scans your code after a new code update, if any issues are found that do NOT match the existing baseline of issues, it will trigger a failure.  NOTE: the failure will continue to trigger until you either modify code to make the issue disappear, or mark the new issue as other than New.

Comment: Thanks for the info, much appreciated. I will take your advice and configure coverity and mu jenkins job to what i need. Thanks again

Comment: in coverity 8.0 , there is option called coverity-desktop-analysis by using this application we can only modified files for scanning that to in local work space , means developers can run coverity before commit/check-in source code to the central repositories.

Comment: I'm using Coverity Connect 8.0.1. Suppose there are 1000 issues which needs to be marked as ignore. Is there an option to mark all the 1000 issues in one go?